# spark ar 2d body tracking not working on some devices

Tags: android, ios, facebook, apache-spark, instagram

I have this strange problem with the file from neck tattoo tutoriel. https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/tutorials/neck-and-shoulder-tattoo/#hiding-the-tattoo-behind-the-clothes

The 2d body tracking is working  on some iphone, but not on other. Not working : iphone 8 os15.6 insta 247, & iphone 13 os15.6 insta 234, iphone S os15.5 insta 245.

Working on : iphone XR 15.5 insta 245, and on a different iphone S os15.5 insta 245, it's working(super weird, same hardware same soft, one working, one not working).

Not working on my android 8.0.0 insta 247, but working on my android inside Spark ar. Likewise hand gesture is also not working  on my android in insta, but working on spark ar.

First, Is there a reason for this odd behavior and is there a workaround for this ?

Second, if not, is there a way to detect if a patch is not supported on the phone that open the filter, and condition the use of the patch to only the device that support it ?

I want to avoid the "your device doesn't support this filter" message. I'm using other function on my filter and I don't want people not to have acces to the filter just because this part break on there phone.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible currently. Older phones do not support some of the newer features because older phones have slower processors and lower quality cameras that would result in poor performance and crashing. A work around might be to create two versions of the effect: one for newer phones, and one for older phones.